# How to modify ~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panel programatically

Tags: lxde, lxpanel

I am trying to read and write the **panel** configuration file (`~/.config/lxpanel/LXDE-pi/panel` ).
I was planning to use some dedicated Python library for the purpose but I cannot recognise the file format.

The file starts like:

```
# lxpanel <profile> config file. Manually editing is not recommended.
# Use preference dialog in lxpanel to adjust config when you can.

Global {
  edge=top
  allign=left
  margin=0
  *... more properties here ...*
  background=0
  backgroundfile=/usr/share/lxpanel/images/background.png
  iconsize=28
  monitor=0
}
Plugin {
  type=space
  Config {
    Size=4
  }
}
Plugin {
  type=menu
  Config {
  ...............
```

It doesn't look like any YAML, INI, JSON or XML file format I am familiar to work with with python libraries.

I know I can use a Python or bash script with some *find/replace* strategy but I would like to have a bit more control on the process.

Could someone please tell me the type of format of this file or give me a hint on how to handle it programmatically?

Comment: Ignoring the warning I see :-). I think its similar to a resource configuration file - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files but cannot think of a program to process it - I would create a finite state machine to handle it but https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/ may have some ideas in the free book.

Comment: @user115418 Well, actually is not a warning but a recommendation and being strict, it refers to "manual modification" and my question is about "programmatical modification".  So, still in the bright side, do not hit me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lxpanel is based off of fbpanel.  There's info on the file format at his github, and the associated project page.  https://github.com/aanatoly/fbpanel

I was looking for info as well, because in the README, he says "Legal values are..." then specifies "systray" as one of the options - however, it's unusable.

Didn't find out 'til later on, while perusing through lxpanel's config, that they were nearly identical, and `tray` works fine in both apps.  Perhaps it was "systray" in a previous version.

Not sure where the parser is located, but I'm certain you can find it, either in that repo, or the one for lxpanel.

If you want to roll-your-own, he gives specifics in that README about how whitespace is stripped, and capitalization is discarded for keywords, *but not their values*.  There were a few other things, mentioned closing brackets `}` had to be on a newline.

Found README location from `man fbpanel`
said it was located at `/usr/share/doc/fbpanel/README`

but that's gzipped, so you'll need to extract it:
`sudo gzip -d /usr/share/doc/fbpanel/README.gz`

If you don't have access to fbpanel, I would imagine that text exists on the repo or website.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed a pity `lxpanel` doesn't use a generic format for its config files.

Make a config template, and then put the required values into it using either search/replace or format specifiers (`%s`, `{}`, f-strings, etc).

Making an actual parser for a custom loosely-specified format you will never use again is a waste of time.